# Where or when is it the right time to call the setMessageListener method on a TopicSubscriber?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jboss5.x, hornetq

I'm trying to subscribe to a `Topic` using a `TopicSubscriber`. To that `TopicSubscriber` I'm trying to assign a `MessageListener`. I added the code below inside the `init()` method of a Servlet that loads on server start-up:

```
String destName = "topic/userManagementTopic";
TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
TopicConnection connection = null;
TopicSession session = null;
Topic topic = null;
InitialContext jndiContext = BlaBla.magicallyBuildTheCorrectInitialContext("userManagementTopic");
connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("java:/JmsXA");

topic = (javax.jms.Topic)jndiContext.lookup(destName);

connection = (TopicConnection)connectionFactory.createConnection("topicUser", "topicPwd");
session = (TopicSession)connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
connection.start();
TopicSubscriber recv = session.createSubscriber(topic);
recv.setMessageListener(new UserManagementTopicListener());
```

Problem is I never get past the last line, because I get

```
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: This method is not applicable inside the application server. See the J2EE spec
```

I've tried to apply the recommended fix I found on the internet, adding `<config-property name="Strict" type="java.lang.Boolean">false</config-property>` to my jms-ds.xml, but that won't fix it.

So, how else could I subscribe to the Topic and indicate my desired `MessageListener`?

I'm using jboss-5.1.0.GA and my app is based on Struts.

Thank you for reading this.

**Later edit: I've gotten past the exception by using `"java:/ConnectionFactory"` for the connection. Now it's even better, I have no errors and the Listener won't process the messages. I'm receiving the messages only when I add MDB adnotations to it, but I don't want to use a MDB. Now what?**

Later edit 2:
I've made it work by binding the listener as follows:

```
String destName = "managementTopic";
Context jndiContext = null;
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
Connection connection = null;
Session session = null;
Destination dest = null;
MessageConsumer consumer = null;
ManagementTopicListener listener = null;
try {
    ref = BlaBla.magicallyBuildTheCorrectInitialContext(destName);

    jndiContext = ref.ctx;

    connectionFactory = connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("XAConnectionFactory");

    dest = (Topic)jndiContext.lookup("topic/" + destName);

    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(ref.getPrinciple(), ref.getCredentials());
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    consumer = session.createConsumer(dest);

    listener = new ManagementTopicListener();
    consumer.setMessageListener(listener);

    connection.start();
    //very important to never close this connection for as long as you want to receive messages
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("kaboom " + e.getStackTrace());
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            System.out.println("exc " + ex.getLinkedException());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed by using the code from the **Later edit 2**

Comment: So, what is the code of `BlaBla.magicallyBuildTheCorrectInitialContext`?